# General case. Prove that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\mathbb P(K)>1-\varepsilon$

Tags: probability, metric-spaces

Let $A$ arbitrary complete metric space, $F$ its Borel sigma algebra

Prove that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\mathbb P(K)>1-\varepsilon$

This is easy to do for $\mathbb R$, how can it be done in the general case?

Comment: Is the metric space also supposed to be separable?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I would like to understand for both cases